# Intel wireless not working after apt update and upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless, intel, adapter

after i updated it just disappeared from the network manager UI https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQsDF.png

```
*-network:0 DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 90:cc:df:40:b5:aa
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-66-generic firmware=48.13675109.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:ec43c000-ec43ffff

[    3.809279] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
```

[    3.809279] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
[    3.956153] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.962113] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    3.962380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.962394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.962405] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.962416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.962429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.962440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.962537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.964818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    3.964821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.964822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.965023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.13675109.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.965041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    4.025734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    4.038968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.039394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.190772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 90:cc:df:40:b5:aa
[    4.309152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0

Comment: I had this very problem..  Was installing multiple systems with 20.04 and somebody accidentally installed using 20.10.1 and suddenly the iwlwifi devics stopped working.

I worked around the issue by installed the linux-firmware from 20.04 on the 20.10 box but (in my case) the long term fix was to install 20.04.

Comment: You can confirm the fault by doing 'dmesg | grep iwlwifi' after a reboot and checking to see if your have 'Direct firmware load for iwlwifi<blah>i failed'  messages..

Comment: @SimonBanks i added the output in the post

Comment: Yes thats looks very much like the issue I found..   The problem is that the linux-firmware package doesn't contain the iwlwifi driver needed to drive the wifi card..

Let me see if I can find the instructions I created to resolve it..

Comment: OK I've posted the solution I used to fix this issue.. let me know if you need any more information?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today when somebody installed Ubuntu 20.10 instead of 20.04 after internet searches and trying lots of things I resolved the problem.

I downloaded the 20.04 latest Linux firmware linux-firmware_1.187.4_all.deb

then I uninstalled the 20.10 version using

```
dpkg -r --force-depends linux-firmware
```

then installed the old package

```
dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.187.4_all.deb
```

Rebooted and everything worked fine...